# MediaProjection API on protected (DRM) content

Tags: android, drm

I'm trying to find informations about the compatibility with DRM protected content and the MediaProjection API.

Specifically, I would like to know if I can record the video from Netflix or other apps that implement DRM protection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is no, not too surprisingly.

From the google docs ( with my bolding):

> Screen capturing and sharing
>   Android 5.0 lets you add screen capturing and screen sharing capabilities to your app with the new android.media.projection APIs. This functionality is useful, for example, if you want to enable screen sharing in a video conferencing app.
>
> The new createVirtualDisplay() method allows your app to capture the contents of the main screen (the default display) into a Surface object, which your app can then send across the network. **The API only allows capturing non-secure screen content**, and not system audio. To begin screen capturing, your app must first request the user’s permission by launching a screen capture dialog using an Intent obtained through the createScreenCaptureIntent() method.

Here is the link: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#ScreenCapture

By 'secure' in this context they mean DRM protected.

Comment: I see, that's a problem. May I ask you if you know any other API that could at least give me a few pixels thumbnail or anything I can use to extract colors from it?

Comment: I'm not aware of any API's to extract colour or frames etc from protected content, but it is possible to apply transformations to protected video if this is meets your need, using GLSurfaceView (I am 99% sure - have not looked at it in detail for a while). It will not give you access to the clear data but it will allow you apply filters to the frames before they are displayed.