# Accessing Android App GPU Context

Tags: android, opengl-es, rendering, gpu

Is it possible to access any Android app's GPU context i.e. what images/graphics the other app is rendering on screen from our custom app. I want to get the images rendered by other app in my app. If yes, how can it be achieved?

Comment: No.  It would be a security nightmare.  You could access financial info, private text messages, passwords, etc.

Comment: See: [MediaProjection API on protected (DRM) content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42158782/295004)

Comment: What if I could safely ask for permissions and proceed?

Comment: You can't. It's not possible.

Comment: @solidpixel Isn't the scenario in main questions somewhat similar to screen sharing, from one phone I can view what is displayed on another phone? (considering we have all necessary permissions)

Comment: @GabeSechan isnt the scenario in the question lik screen sharing from one phone I can view what is displayed on another phone? (considering we have all necessary permissions)

Comment: Quiet correct - this used to need root, but Android added this in version 5.something. See this package for screencast permissions https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/package-summary

Comment: @GabeSechan Since I want to do this only for VR apps, can't we hook something to the Google VR service and apply some custom distortion ? I just want to apply some custom distortion for any random VR app from my service and render back to screen.